# ASPxGridView page works for some users, not for others. WebForm model using C#, ASP, SQL Express

Tags: webforms, devexpress, aspxgridview

I am debugging a website built on the WebForms model, using ASP, C# as codebehind, and SQL Express 2008 R2.  I am trying to debug a page that uses an ASPxGridView, which is populated from the .aspx file, and the dataset is uses is created there as well.  The data is selected using

```
 SelectCommand="SELECT MachineID, ProgramNo, (CONVERT (VARCHAR(19), Start, 120)) as Start,(CONVERT (VARCHAR(12), Stop,114)) as StopTime, WorkCount, PartCount as TotalWorkCount,(CONVERT (VARCHAR(12), Stop-start,114)) as PartCycle  FROM Program WHERE (MachineID = @MachineID) AND (WorkCount &gt; 0) AND (CONVERT (VARCHAR(19), Start, 120) &gt;= @StartDate) AND (CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), Start, 120) &lt;= @EndDate) order by Start Desc">
```

The problem is that most users can login and the page works perfectly, but a few users see the following error in the web browser:

> A field or property with name 'PartCycle' was not found in the selected data source. Possible causes of this error may be the following: an incorrect or case-insensitive spelling of the grid column name; assigning a wrong or not properly initialized data source to the grid.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: A field or property with name 'PartCycle' was not found in the selected data source. Possible causes of this error may be the following: an incorrect or case-insensitive spelling of the grid column name; assigning a wrong or not properly initialized data source to the grid.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): A field or property with name 'PartCycle' was not found in the selected data source. Possible causes of this error may be the following: an incorrect or case-insensitive spelling of the grid column name; assigning a wrong or not properly initialized data source to the grid.]
>      DevExpress.Web.Data.WebDataControllerProvider.GetRowValueByControllerRow(Int32 controllerRow, String fieldName, Boolean isDesignTime) +300
>      DevExpress.Web.Data.WebDataControllerProvider.GetRowValue(Int32 visibleIndex, String fieldName, Boolean isDesignTime) +203
>      DevExpress.Web.Data.WebDataProxy.GetRowValue(Int32 visibleIndex, String fieldName) +77

As you can see, PartCycle is not a column in the tables, but is used as an alias for (CONVERT (VARCHAR(12), Stop-start,114)).  To put a twist in the plot, I can view the problem data just fine when I am logged into the site as an Administrator. The users who see this error have various ASPNET Roles, but each have access to the data in the tables selected.

Comment: Maibe you exceed the limitations of SQL Server Express? The maximum size of the database - 4GB, CPU sockets - 1 and amount of memory - 1GB

Comment: First -  I don't see the field "PartCycle" in the query. It's possible that the field was renamed in the gridView. Check the columns in the GridView designer or code. Second - It's possible some users are viewing a different page. - is this hosted in a webfarm enviornment?

Comment: @Boris Gappov, I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, which has a max database size of 10GB.  I am not sure about how much memory is it using.

Comment: @Saif Khan, PartCycle is in the query:  '...(CONVERT (VARCHAR(12), Stop-start,114)) as PartCycle  FROM Program WHERE... ' .  I have checked the GridView columns, and the code looks ok.  The site is hosted on a single server.

Comment: Please write data source markup

Comment: @Boris Gappov,  I just found that the .CS file has a similar   SelectCommand code for the sqlDataSource and it doesn't include PartCycle.  Commenting this out allows the page to load properly.

Answer (score 2):

Its because ASPxGridView Caches the Columns.

In your case, your datasource is dynamic i.e. different for different users.

Make sure to Clear the Columns before binding ASPxGridView.

To Clear the Columns:

```
agvObject.Columns.Clear();
```